# Methods for taping injured wrists

Tags: rock-climbing

I would like to ask If someone knows a method for taping wrists that supports wrists. I got stretched tendon in my wrist and I would like to support it with tape. I have only found methods for making tape gloves that are used to protect hand from rocks etc. but haven't found anything that would support my wrist/tendons in forearm/wrist.

Comment: Hello and welcome to The Great Outdoors, David! While you might get a good answer here, I strongly suggest you see a physicist or other medical personnel to get professional advice.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen Hello and thanks. I visited my doctor and she said it is not serious and said that I should just support my wrist with bandage. But since the bandage is quite big and makes it harder to climb/belay I just wanted to know if there is a way to support my wrist with a tape, if not I will surely use the bandage as my doctor suggested. :)

Comment: Kinesio tape is an option. My wife does it, so I'll ask her what would be appropriate. Can you clarify which tendon.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I don't know the name of the tendon but it is the one on the right when you look on your left forearm.

Comment: @David: May be you can look for products like Wrist Braces? There are plenty of similar sorts on healthkart

Comment: Tight athletic tape around the base of the wrist will work. If you tape such that it impedes the motion of the wrist that will probably support "stretched tendon(s)" however without more detail about the exact tendon that is affected it's hard to say with detail where to tape.

Comment: This is related to [my question here](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3480/1908). Possible duplicate? There's some grey area there, mine is intended to be all-encompassing, but this is specifically on the wrist, but related to climbing it seems. I don't know...just throwing it out there.

Comment: @Liam My answer is primarily about "tape gloves" the question clear includes this subject.  "*For example: I'm having intermittent wrist pain. How can I supportively tape it, yet not restrict it too much, and also not completely cover the palm.*"  Other answers are welcome!  Voting to close.

Comment: Good point @Mr.Wizard. I hadn't noticed that